# Entity Framework 1-1 relationship: "The navigation property was not found on the dependent type "

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to define 1:1 relationship in Entity Framework 6, code first. I've followed this tutorial: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

In my example, one customer can have one specific address.
Regarding the 1:1 relationships I've read so much and I have no idea what's the *correct* way to define that type of relationship. So, here are my classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string AddressName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my initialization:

```
List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>
{
    new Address { AddressName = "12 Main St., Houston TX 77001" },
    new Address { AddressName = "1007 Mountain Dr., Gotham NY 10286" }
};

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>
{
    new Customer { CustomerName = "John Doe", Address = addresses.ElementAt(0) },
    new Customer { CustomerName = "Bruce Wayne", Address = addresses.ElementAt(1) }
};
customers.ForEach(c => context.Customer.Add(c));
context.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see, I'm not inserting addresses directly, but via customer objects. Is this the correct way to implement 1:1 relationship?

Anyway, when I deploy my application, I get this error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'AddressId' on type 'aspdotnetmvc.Models.Address' is not valid. The navigation property 'Customer' was not found on the dependent type

What could be wrong here? I'm following tutorial to the letter.

Comment: Add `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }` to your address object. The ForeignKey attribute isn't linking the Address object to a Customer object, but is trying to link it to a Customer property on itself.

Comment: Yeah, you missed a letter :)

Comment: Yeah indeed, thanks guys! Actually, according to tutorial, I should have done something like this in the `OnModelCreating` method: `modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasOptional(s => s.Address).WithRequired(ad => ad.Customer);`
I left this out and it still works correctly - so what's going on?

Comment: @uglycode I don't remember what EF does off-hand by default. With the modelBuilder you defined in your comment, it says each customer can have an address, but each address must have a customer. This will effect the way it creates the DB for you(whether or not the FK column will be nullable). It is possible without that, EF will enforce that a customer must have an address as well and will fail to save a customer to the db without it having an address. Play around with it for sure, but you should see the difference in the schemas generated.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Just one final question: I had the same classes, just without `[ForeignKey("Customer")]` and `public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }`, everything else was the same, and it worked as well. What did I do with this?

Comment: You must do specify Dependent and Principle with `HasRequired` and `HasOptinal` on model builder.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you leave everything out (no annotation or fluent code), EF will follow its [conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx). You were getting the error because you referred to a nav property that didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For specifying **Dependent** and **Principle** in Database model relation you can use FluntAPI Method For Map Relations, For Example:

override this method form you Context Class:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
          .HasOptional(x => x.Address)
          .WithRequired(c => x.Customer)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
  }
```

Your Address Model **Address.cs**:

```
public class Address
{
  public int AddressId { get; set; }
  public string AddressName { get; set; }
  public Customer Cutomer {get;set;}
}
```

After Insert Codes On Your Application Add migration and Update Database.